# React Redux: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

For some background info, I am new to Redux however I have already implemented a redux function in a different class for my same project. The error lies in the handleDragStop function where this.props is undefined.  I am sure that the action setSpotifySelectedTrackFeature is valid as I made it based on the same procedure I have followed before. The only difference being this component defined as a const as opposed to a class (in which I used redux function successfully) which I believe is the problem. Can anyone guide me with this? Thank you

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {setSpotifySelectedTrackFeature} from "../actions/index";

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Slider from '@material-ui/core/Slider';
import HelpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Help';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';


function valuetext(value) {
  return `${value}`;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: 300
  },
});

function SpotifyRangeSlider(details) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = useState([35, 65]);


  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  const handleDragStop = (event, value) => {
    this.props.setSpotifySelectedTrackFeature(
        {
          "name": details.sliderLabel,
          "min": value[0],
          "max": value[1],
          "details": details.sliderDetails
        }
    )
    console.log("updated")
  }

  return (
    <div className="slider">
      <Typography id="range-slider" gutterBottom>
        {details.sliderLabel}
       <Tooltip title={details.sliderDetails}>
          <IconButton>
            <HelpIcon />
          </IconButton> 
       </Tooltip>
      </Typography>
      <Slider
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onChangeCommitted={handleDragStop}
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        aria-labelledby="range-slider"
        getAriaValueText={valuetext}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

//Used to retrieve data from the store(reducers)
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    spotifySelectedTrackReducer: state.spotifySelectedTrackReducer
  };
}

//Used to send data so that an action can be called
function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return {
      ...bindActionCreators({setSpotifySelectedTrackFeature}, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(SpotifyRangeSlider)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you you are trying to reference `this.props` in a functional, non-class component. There is no `this.props` for a functional component, similar to how you couldn't really do `this.state` in this component either. Try instead accessing the mapped state to prop `spotifySelectedTrackReducer` via the functional component props, in this case you called them `details`:

```
const handleDragStop = (event, value) => {
  details.setSpotifySelectedTrackFeature(
    {
      "name": details.sliderLabel,
      "min": value[0],
      "max": value[1],
      "details": details.sliderDetails
    }
  )
  console.log("updated")
}
```

At minimum try logging out the value of `details` and see what props are available. Another option is to use [react-redux hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) to get values from the store, which can be easier:

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

// ...
function SpotifyRangeSlider(details) {
  const spotifySelectedTrackReducer = useSelector(state => state.spotifySelectedTrackReducer)
  // ...
  // dispatch action using a hook also
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  dispatch(setSpotifySelectedTrackFeature(someArguments))
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: @Wishal That first argument to a functional component, such as this one, would be `props`. You just gave the variable the name "details" instead of "props". You could call it "foo" if you wanted. Or you could destructure properties directly such as `function SpotifyRangeSlider({ sliderLabel, sliderDetails, spotifySelectedTrackReducer })`

Comment: I Agree! when you are using FunctionComponent you should use React or React-redux Hooks. Otherwise, you will continuously be facing this sort of issues.

Comment: @Alexander Yea my bad! I eventually realized it before you sent this comment. So if I understood correctly in this context since it is a non class component, this.props is practically details. Thank you again!

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky you should add `useDispatch` hook as well for `setSpotifySelectedTrackFeature` instead of accessing it via `details`.

Comment: Yes, `this.props` and `this.state` will only really be applicable for class components, as in `class MyComponent extends React.Component`.

Comment: @usafder In terms of functionality what difference would it make using the useDispatch hook as opposed to accessing it via details?

Comment: I would either go with hooks and access the store values or `dispatch` you need via hooks or use `connect` and access via details/props. I'd choose one or the other, otherwise it may make things inconsistent. `connect`, `mapStateToProps`, and `mapDispatchToProps` does have advanced usages that you can read about in their documentation, but for something as simple as getting a value from store or dispatching an action, hooks may be easier, just my opinion.

Comment: I agree with what @AlexanderStaroselsky said.

Answer (score 1):

I the current context `details` is the parameter which you are receiving as props. And we use this.props when we are using class components but you are using FunctionComponent. So, I think it should be `details.setSpotifySelectedTrackFeature` instead of `this.props.setSpotifySelectedTrackFeature`

Comment: Thank you that indeed was the issue!

Comment: Welcome to the SO with power :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no this.props in funtional components. They look like this:

```
function MyFuntionalComponent(props) {
  console.log(props.someThing)
}

//You can also destructure them how I like it
function MyFuntionalComponent({ name, id, someThing }) {
  console.log(someThing)
}
```